# How to sort (through filters) a table based on two different columns?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table in Google sheets which I need to filter on a primary and a secondary column  An analogous example would be points of different teams in a football league.  The primary filter would be decreasing values of total points in the season.  If the total points of two teams are the same, then the secondary filter would kick in which would be based on a decreasing value of goal difference.

So, let's say teams A and B have the same points.  But B has a superior goal difference.  So B should be placed higher than A.

Is there a way this can be done without complicated functions?

Answer (score 1):

function is pretty simple:

```
=SORT(A1:C, 2, 0, 3, 0)
```

`2`, `3` being columns and `0` for decreasing

[image: 0]